# problems with current_company argument on search_people method on linkedin_api

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

```py
from linkedin_api import *

# Authenticate using any Linkedin account credentials
api = Linkedin('**************@g*****.com', '***')

print(api.search_people(current_company = '1009'))
```

I've tried to use this code to get people working on IBM, but all I get is a empty list.

I tried to replace with

```py
current_company = 'ibm'
```

and with caps lock also. But didn't get any new result

I can get the results without any arguments, but I need to search people working on a specific company

Comment: What is `linkedin_api`? Are you trying to report a bug with this library?

Comment: it's this https://pypi.org/project/linkedin-api/, it can do search and automation. I'm not trying to report a bug, just trying to get a list of all people working at a specific company on my social network of linkedin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `search_people` function requires (a `list` of) company URN IDs as input for the `current_company` argument so `'ibm'` is not valid. The input should be a `str`ing-based identifier with the format: `urn:{namespace}:{entityType}:{id}`.

Comment: that's helpfull, thank you, but just one more question, how do I get the urn of IBM in this format and what is the urn of IBM?

Comment: For some reason it isn't listed when searching on Google (or I would've provided it in my answer). I did find one source (I think) but it required a login which I don't have at the moment. Here's another link explaining it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api?view=li-lms-2023-03&tabs=http), I didn't have time to read through it but the answer should be in there.

Comment: And here's the documentation FYI: https://linkedin-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html